# getting started with appium using ruby

Tags: ruby, automation, appium

I am configuring my windows 7 machine with ruby. can you please suggest on compatible appium and ruby versions to get started and Hybrid apps automation. Also please mention the gems to be installed.

Also, how can we switch from native view to webview using ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following link to configure and install the required gems for automation testing

[In-depth Hassle-free installation and configuration of cucumber with ruby guide](https://thewirelessworld.wordpress.com/2015/10/07/web-testing-with-ruby-setup-guide/)

Now for swithcing from Native view to WebView,
First get a list of available contexts for your application using

```
driver.available_contexts
```

This will give you an array of contexts.From the returned array (if "webview" is returned) you can choose to switch contexts using  `driver.switch_to.context(webview)`
(where webview is a context returned from the first command)